# OpenGL depth buffer or depth test does not work when rendering with a shared context

Tags: opengl, opengl-3, fbo

I have a very specific OpenGL setup where the 3D geometry in the scene does not render. There is some depth-related state in the OpenGL context that illudes me.

This is in a production engine at work where we added shared context support with multiple window contexts. We are doing the rendering to a framebuffer object owned by the shared context, then blitting the color attachment renderbuffer to a window using a different context.

The clear color is showing in the resulting blit to the window, but not the 3D scene geometry itself, so we know the framebuffer and renderbuffer objects are at least partially correct.

To illustrate, I refactored a sample from the LearnOpenGL website to illustrate my bug. It shows up there as well, so I am clear this is something I am missing.

Here is the GitHub project where I made three commits to a working framebuffer sample so that it rendered to the framebuffer using a shared context and then blits the result: [Framebuffer Shared Context Experiment](https://github.com/amesgames/LearnOpenGL/commits/amesgames/framebuffer-shared-context-experiment)

Here is most of the source code that produces the buggy result. I snipped a few sections that went unchanged.

```
    // glfw dummy window creation
    // --------------------
    GLFWwindow* dummy = NULL;
#if USE_SHARED_CONTEXT
    dummy = glfwCreateWindow(1, 1, "Dummy", NULL, NULL);
    if (dummy == NULL)
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to create dummy GLFW window" << std::endl;
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(dummy);
#endif

    // glfw window creation
    // --------------------
    GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(SCR_WIDTH, SCR_HEIGHT, "LearnOpenGL", NULL, dummy);
    if (window == NULL)
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to create GLFW window" << std::endl;
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }
    glfwShowWindow(window);
#if !USE_SHARED_CONTEXT
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
#endif

    // <snip creation of shared resources>
    // <snip creation of un-shared vertex array>

    // framebuffer configuration
    // -------------------------
    unsigned int framebuffer;
    glGenFramebuffers(1, &framebuffer);
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, framebuffer);

#if 1
    // create a color attachment render buffer
    unsigned int Colorbuffer;
    glGenRenderbuffers(1, &Colorbuffer);
    glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, Colorbuffer);
    glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_RGBA8, SCR_WIDTH, SCR_HEIGHT); // use a single renderbuffer object for both a depth AND stencil buffer.
    glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_RENDERBUFFER, Colorbuffer); // now actually attach it
#else
    // create a color attachment texture
    unsigned int textureColorbuffer;
    glGenTextures(1, &textureColorbuffer);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureColorbuffer);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, SCR_WIDTH, SCR_HEIGHT, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, NULL);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureColorbuffer, 0);
#endif

    // create a renderbuffer object for depth and stencil attachment (we won't be sampling these)
    unsigned int rbo;
    glGenRenderbuffers(1, &rbo);
    glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, rbo);
    glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_DEPTH24_STENCIL8, SCR_WIDTH, SCR_HEIGHT); // use a single renderbuffer object for both a depth AND stencil buffer.
    glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_STENCIL_ATTACHMENT, GL_RENDERBUFFER, rbo); // now actually attach it
    // now that we actually created the framebuffer and added all attachments we want to check if it is actually complete now
    if (glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER) != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE)
        cout << "ERROR::FRAMEBUFFER:: Framebuffer is not complete!" << endl;
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);

    // render loop
    // -----------
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        // <snip timing and input>

    #if USE_SHARED_CONTEXT
        // use shared context because that is what is holding our framebuffer and vao.
        // -----
        glfwMakeContextCurrent(dummy);
    #endif

        // render
        // ------
        // bind to framebuffer and draw scene as we normally would to color texture 
        glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, framebuffer);
        glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST); // enable depth testing (is disabled for rendering screen-space quad)

        // make sure we clear the framebuffer's content
        glClearColor(1.0f, 0.1f, 0.1f, 1.0f);
        glClearDepth(1.0f);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        // following render is unchanged
        shader.use();
        glm::mat4 model;
        glm::mat4 view = camera.GetViewMatrix();
        glm::mat4 projection = glm::perspective(camera.Zoom, (float)SCR_WIDTH / (float)SCR_HEIGHT, 0.1f, 100.0f);
        shader.setMat4("view", view);
        shader.setMat4("projection", projection);
        // cubes
        glBindVertexArray(cubeVAO);
        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, cubeTexture);
        model = glm::translate(model, glm::vec3(-1.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f));
        shader.setMat4("model", model);
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 36);
        model = glm::mat4();
        model = glm::translate(model, glm::vec3(2.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f));
        shader.setMat4("model", model);
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 36);
        // floor
        glBindVertexArray(planeVAO);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, floorTexture);
        shader.setMat4("model", glm::mat4());
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6);
        glBindVertexArray(0);

#if 1
    #if USE_SHARED_CONTEXT
        // use window context for presentation via blit.
        // -----
        glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

        // temorary framebuffer for visible window since framebuffers are not shared
        // -------------------------
        unsigned int readFramebuffer;
        glGenFramebuffers(1, &readFramebuffer);
        glBindFramebuffer(GL_READ_FRAMEBUFFER, readFramebuffer);
        glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, Colorbuffer);
        glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_RGBA8, SCR_WIDTH, SCR_HEIGHT);
        glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_READ_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_RENDERBUFFER, Colorbuffer);
    #endif

        glBindFramebuffer(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
        glBlitFramebuffer(0, 0, SCR_WIDTH, SCR_HEIGHT, 0, 0, SCR_WIDTH, SCR_HEIGHT, GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT, GL_NEAREST);

    #if USE_SHARED_CONTEXT
        glDeleteFramebuffers(1, &readFramebuffer);
    #endif
#else
        // now bind back to default framebuffer and draw a quad plane with the attached framebuffer color texture
        glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
        glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST); // disable depth test so screen-space quad isn't discarded due to depth test.
        // clear all relevant buffers
        glClearColor(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f); // set clear color to white (not really necessery actually, since we won't be able to see behind the quad anyways)
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        screenShader.use();
        glBindVertexArray(quadVAO);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureColorbuffer);   // use the color attachment texture as the texture of the quad plane
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6);
#endif

        // glfw: swap buffers and poll IO events (keys pressed/released, mouse moved etc.)
        // -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents();
    }
// <snip epilog>
```

You can toggle the `USE_SHARED_CONTEXT` compile-time switch to remove the little bit of code that renders using a shared context.

Answer (score 1):

I was missing a call to glViewport for the shared render context.

The value of the Viewport was defaulted to (0, 0) -> (width, height) for the context used by the visible window. The shared render context had been defaulted to (0, 0) -> (1, 1) because I used a width and height of 1 for the non-visible GLFW window.